# Centering something without margin

Tags: html, css, centering

Is it possible to center something without using margin: auto;? My div cannot be a set size because the width will change according to it's contents and even so I would not know how wide it would be since it's text inside (There is a div around text because there are multiple `<p>`'s). Is there any other way of aligning in center without knowing your width of the object?

```css
div#contents {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 50px 100px 50px 100px;
 border: 3px solid black;
}

table#socialmedia {
 height: 100px;
 margin-top: 10px;
 float: left;

}

table#support {
 height: 25px;
 margin-top: 10px;
 float: left;

}

table#external {
 margin-top: 10px;
 float: left;

}

div#footerdivider {
 width: 1px;
 height: 120px;
 margin: 0px 50px 0px 50px;
 background-color: #424242;
 float: left;
}

p.footerlinks {
 font-size: 20px;
 color: #8C8CFF;
 text-align: center;
```

```html
<div id="contents">
 <table id="socialmedia">
  <tr><td><a href=""><p class="footerlinks">Facebook</p></a></td></tr>
  <tr><td><a href=""><p class="footerlinks">Twitter</p></a></td></tr>
  <tr><td><a href=""><p class="footerlinks">YouTube</p></a></td></tr>
  <tr><td><a href=""><p class="footerlinks">Steam</p></a></td></tr>
 </table>
 <div id="footerdivider">
 </div>
 <table id="support">
  <tr><td><a href=""><p class="footerlinks">Email Us (Click to copy)</p></a></td></tr>
 </table>
 <div id="footerdivider">
 </div>
 <table id="external">
 </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Which elements are you trying to center?

Comment: Try this - [Centering in CSS: A Complete Guide](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/) and [THE COMPLETE GUIDE TO CENTERING A DIV](http://www.tipue.com/blog/center-a-div/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Horizontally center a div in a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/horizontally-center-a-div-in-a-div) (this post proposes a bunch of solutions, many of which don't involve `margin: 0 auto`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To center align an item **without** the use of `margin: 0 auto;`, you could use flexbox if the browsers you are working with support it.

Consider the following snippet;

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 5px 0;
}
.item {
    background-color: red;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">Praesent ultrices nec quam at blandit. Pellentesque elementum ullamcorper lobortis.</div>
</div>
```

There is a good article on flexbox over @ css-tricks.com you can check out [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Hope that helps you out!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```css
div.your_element {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

> display: table   (to center a fluid div:)
>
> margin: 0 auto   (to center tables)

Answer (score 0):

I'think if you set the margin to auto.
It is usually working on horizontal.

```
div {
      margin: auto;

}
```